# 2 Pin Wire to Board Connector

Tags: identification, connector

I need to replace some 2 pin wire to board connectors, but I am unsure of how to identify the connector in question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Several things may help us identify the connector.  (1) Examine the connector with a magnifying glass.  There may be text molded into the connector.  Add the text to your question.  There may be a name of the manufacturer, or the part number, or some other clue.  (2) Measure the pitch between the pins of the connector.  Add it to your question.  (3) Take picture of the jack which this connector plugs into.  Add it to your question.  It may jog somebody's memory.

Comment: In addition to Nick's recommendations, you can provide more detail about what device this connector came from.

Comment: We need the **exact** [pitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+pitch), please.